# How to find the coefficients in the Fourier series solution of a 1-D heat equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, integral-transforms, heat-equation

I am trying to use Fourier's method to solve a problem.

$u(x,t) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty B_ne^{-(n\pi C / L)^2 t}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right), B_n=\frac2L\int_0^L \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)f(x) \,dx$

Of the $1-D$ heat equation $t\gt0$ on $0\leq x\leq L$ with boundary $u(0,t)=0=u(L,t)$, $t\gt 0$ and initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$, $0\leq x \leq L$

---

Now first I want to calculate $B_n=\frac2L\int_0^L \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)f(x) \,dx$, and so I look for $f(x)$, now $f(x)$ appears to be equal to $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty B_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$, which means I have:

$B_n = \frac2L\int_0^L \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\left[\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty B_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\right] \,dx$

Is this correct, shall I work no the above expression, or is there something I should first note.

Comment: "The head equation." Now that's something many people would be interested in.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Are you mocking my misspelling, or the general boring nature of the question(or both)?

Comment: You have already stated the solution to the problem at the beginning.  I don't know what else you are trying to do with what you are given.

Comment: @RonGordon I need to solve for $B_n$, my $u(x,t)$ has $B_n$ within it, and $B_n$ is defined there, however, to solve for $B_n$, I get that integral with $B_n$ inside of a sum and an integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so I look for $f(x)$

Don't look for it in your solution: look in the statement of the problem. Is it given there (like $f(x)=3\sin^2 x$ or something)? If there is no concrete  initial condition, there cannot be an concrete solution: the formula that you have for $u$ at the beginning of the post is the answer.

Putting the series with $B_n$ into the formula for evaluating $B_n$ is akin to [plugging a UPS into itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231739/). All you can get from this is $B_n=B_n$.